# remote access for Mac (unattended)

Tags: macos, remote-control

What are the good options for configure a Mac (MacBook Air) for unattended remote access, for a family member?

The primary purpose is reliable (if occasional) unattended remote access that's very resistant to failures. (This assumes a persistent and reliable internet and network connection.) This makes it different from most use cases of primarily local use, and make it more of a server if you will - always online, always can be accessed and checked on. In a way, makes me want to set up a lightweight Dell or an HPE server with lights-out access (iDRAC, ILO) so the system can be accessed (and revived if it's offline) in nearly any state as long as there is a network connection. Yet a server is out of question - the chosen computer is a laptop, a MacBook Air for the time being. (Switching to a Windows laptop or desktop is certainly a possibility if that makes it easier.)

> (Side note. This seems to be a common theme where non-technical people need help occasionally with their computers, have technical family members or friends willing to help, and all that's needed is a fairly simple and reliable NAT-traversing remote access service. Yet it seems all the usual suspects including ARD, CRD and TeamViewer have substantial roadblocks limiting or preventing their use for the purpose. Even Apple killed their "Back to my Mac" service. Anyone knows why?)

##### Caveats / notes / needed features / requirements:

- **Purpose**.

  - This is for a family member who pretty much never uses a computer, never used one before, but once in a while needs to partake in a Zoom meeting.
  - The family member could use help from one of the nerds in the family to set the meeting up and otherwise do routine maintenance on the computer (OS and application updates, etc.) To put it in other words, the entire purpose and MO of this computer is to be remotely accessed reliably and present a specific UI (Zoom meeting, Google Photos, specific web page, etc.) to the local user, e.g.:

    1. IT-minded nerd family member accesses the computer remotely and sets it up for e.g. a Zoom meeting.
    2. The same IT fairy phones the non-nerd family member in question and invites them to sit down in front of the computer and participate in the meeting,
    3. The non-nerd family member sits down and participates in the meeting
    4. The nerd then closes the Zoom meeting remotely, and signs off.
    5. The nerd also occasionally runs OS and application updates unattended, i.e. the local user doesn't need (and prefers not) to know about it.
- **Price**: free to ~$10/yr. Remote access is only needed once in a blue moon (roughly once a month, sometimes twice, sometimes once in 6 months). I understand remote access solution developers need to be paid - yet most paid plans are in the range of $10-20/mo - and that seems a little high for the type of service I am looking for.
- Must **traverse NATs** easily. No DDNS, traffic or port forwarding setup: the MBA (MacBook Air) needs to be accessible wherever it is, via whatever internet connection it's on, whether behind a specially configured router or any other network. I.e. it should work like TeamViewer or Chrome Remote Desktop - but not like ARD (Apple Remote Desktop), MRD (Microsoft Remote Desktop), built-in VNC or SSH server - i.e. be able to traverse NATs w/o special configs.
- **Security**: must be reasonably secure, e.g. fully integrated with a Google or Apple ID account - which in turn can be set up with with MFA.
- **Reliable, stable**: CRD (Chrome Remote Desktop) seems to break and go offline easily. Quite a few times I've run into situations where it would stop working because it needed an update, the pre-configured PIN would stop working inexplicably, etc.
- **Easy to use** (for the family member in question): TeamViewer (the free edition at least) seems to be confusing to most non-nerds with incessant pop-ups. Ideally the service would be as seamless and unobtrusive as possible, while providing a clear indication to the person at the computer that it's being accessed remotely by someone.

##### What I've tried

- Searched the interwebs and ask AI for popular / common RDC (remote desktop connection) solutions for Macs, adjusting search terms for solutions suitable for personal use, family members and friends, easy to use, reliable, ad-free. There are a number of answers here on SE and sister sites ("Ask Different") - yet I haven't found one that asks quite the same question, and quite a few answers are stale, e.g. mention tools (like "Back to my Mac") that are no longer available.
- Using CRD (Chrome Remote Desktop), TeamViewer free edition, LMI, various VNC flavors, ARD, ARD, SSH and probably a ton of other things I am forgetting for personal and family purposes, and also various VPN clients and flavors, MS RDC, RDS and RDCM, and of course ARD and MRD on a Mac, on the job.
- CRD and TeamViewer (TmV) are the top recommendations, however:

  - Unlike TmV, CRD doesn't seem to work well for multiple users - or at least I couldn't figure out how to set up one other nerd (family member) to remote into the target computer using their own account.
  - As mentioned before, CRD seems to break frequently and catastrophically: a Chrome update could render it offline, a PIN that was working before would all of a sudden stop working, etc.
  - Once CRD (or any other RDC tool) stops working, it's catastrophic: attempting to walk a family member whose only computing experience is a flip phone (not even a smartphone) through troubleshooting steps trying to revive CRD, TmV or any other tool is an exercise in futility and frustration for all sides.
  - Perhaps CRD works well enough when used frequently - yet if it's only once in a few months, the failure rate becomes too high - it seems to break on every 3rd of 4th access attempt. (... and then we'd have to find someone locally to pay a visit try to resuscitate the computer, which can take weeks sometimes.)
  - TeamViewer:

    - those free edition's pop-ups can it very disorienting for a non-technical user
    - paid plans are way too expensive
    - even with those pop-ups, can the free edition be relied on for the next few years? Their [pricing page](https://service.teamviewer.com/en-us/overview/e) doesn't mention the free edition, I couldn't find it mentioned or linked to from their main page, and even if it continues to be available, it can probably be counted on to become even more annoying going forward.
- There is also [DWS Remote Control](https://www.dwservice.net/en/home.html). Did *not* try it, in fact never heard of it, do not see a lot of recommendations for it, and am reluctant to try it given the need for inherent and well thought out security.

##### Question(s):

- Can you think of a reasonably priced RDC solution that meets the above requirements in terms of price, reliability, ease of use, and being not too annoying?
- Is there a fairly up-to-date resource (that's not too click-baity or ad-infested) that tracks RDC solutions and tools and could give me an insight into what might be the best solution for this use case?

Thank you!

P.S. I will likely be editing and revising this question as new info comes along.

Comment: I use ZeroTier (free, virtualized network) + Apple Remote Desktop (paid, App store) + Amphetamine (free, to keep remote computer awake). Needs some setup but after that just works.

Comment: As much as we love details and previous research, in your case the question gets extremely long and you may loose a lot of people because they click away after one screen of text. Also, at least partly the questions seems to ask for opinions (see the comparision between CRD and TV for instance) which is generally off-topic here. At the end of the day, there are a bunch of suitable tools (which you already list), we can't really make the decision for you.

Comment: I get it - short attention span - yet I don't mind losing those. What I did was summarize my problem and the requirements in the 1st two sentences (and then summarize again at the end) so people who may have insight could contribute and those who don't - could move on.

Comment: Also: the requirements actually rule out CRD (no multi-user support) and somewhat rule out TmV (pop-ups - or too expensive), so the question remains unresolved. Perhaps it **can't** be resolved, and in that case, the "wall of text" could be **very** useful to someone else in the same boat and save a few hours of research. (Would have definitely saved me some.) P.S. Who is "we"? I keep getting pummelled by frivolous moderation here despite being in tech for 30+ years - is "we" the infamous SO moderation crowd?

Comment: If the requirements already rule out specific tools, why even mention them? Also, besides this reads a lot like a "I'm shopping for a product matching $LONG_LIST_OF_REQUIREMENTS" it also asks several questions at once (and some of them are clearly off-topic).

Comment: no wonder people are fleeing the platform... yikes.

Comment: Sticking to one question per question is a core rule on all SE sites. Currently I count at least three: "why did Apple remove 'Back to my Mac'" (which is opinion-based), "Can you think of a reasonably priced RDC solution that meets the above requirements " (which is a shopping question as another user has already pointed out) and "Is there a fairly up-to-date resource that tracks RDC solutions" (which asks for off-site resources), which one do you have answered?

Comment: Also, one requirement states "must be reasonably secure, e.g. fully integrated with a Google or Apple ID account" as a requirement but claim that the Screen Sharing solution (which really is your best option here) doesn't work because it requires an AppleID. Not sure how this adds up.

Comment: It adds up if you read it carefully and take care to understand the difference between "e.g." and "must", as well as why that "best option" you mentioned is far from it (being the "best" or even remotely suitable). Yet it's far from the 1st time a snap, frivolous and bad moderation decision is made w/o fully reading and comprehending the context, and then mods get all defensive with a bunch of excuses. Which tells me exactly what to do: get out of here fast. Have fun!

Comment: The question was put on hold by several AD users. You can always post a question on our Meta site to  discuss/appeal the hold mods or users put on a question.

Answer (score 3):

If the remote user is going to be there to hit the 'accept' button, then Screen Sharing [using their Apple ID to find them] is virtually idiot-proof.

It does need the Mac to be running & online, though, it's not bullet-proof in that respect, but it works so long as they can press a button as it tries to connect. It needs no tunnelling or other expertise at all; you don't have to try punch your way through firewalls from the outside. You don't need to expose the Mac to any third party's remote central service [Teamviewer, NoMachine et al] or leave any ports open other than those that Apple are already using outbound for iCloud.

[image]

Spotlight can find the app - it's well buried down inside CoreServices - and will also list your recent connections.

It's also *already installed* & ready to go, so long as their Apple ID is signed in. You don't need to drive there first to set it up.

I use it for my octogenarian parents, the other side of the country. We usually hook up with a FaceTime call to start the process - for those "Do you mean click this?" moments before we're in. Once it's made the connection, it includes two-way voice, so we can usually hang up the phone at that point.

Comment: 1. Not working for me even on the same network. (Finds the ID, requests acceptance, then "not available" a minute or so after accepting.) 2. The "client" doesn't have an Apple ID, doesn't have an email address. Asking them to set it up and maintain it - is extra work neither side is ready for - unless it's otherwise indeed bullet-proof - which from a little bit of testing - it doesn't seem to be. I'll play with it a bit more - yet from the need to "accept" (making it **not** unattended) to heavy dependence on Apple ID - this just doesn't seem to be the solution. Thanks!

Comment: You really need an Apple ID to properly 'own' the Mac you have. If they don't have one, & the computer is not registered to one, then of course it's not going to find it. [btw, for testing you cannot use your own Apple ID - it doesn't work to connect to 'yourself', even on a different computer. I wish it would, that's what was great about 'Back to My Mac'] Once initialised it needs zero maintenance, it's a built-in function.

Comment: upvoted - but can't make it the solution - doesn't meet requirements. It's a cool idea; may be suitable for other purposes - and I am really happy it's working for you and your family. I've heard of Screen Sharing in the past but don't think I ever played with it - thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Then this becomes a 'software request', which is off-topic. You're back to the regular commercial offerings - TeamViewer, NoMachine, ZeroTier etc. [You're also going to have to drive to the far end to set it up.]

Comment: "off topic"? whatever :) (there's always reddit, thankfully) (curious: why did you answer if the answer clearly doesn't meet requirements? What were you hoping for?) Re: far end: I am there now, leaving in a couple of days, hoping to set up the newly acquired MBA so that it's indeed bullet-proof and nobody has to "drive to the far end" to set it up for a video meeting.

Comment: To use a built-in service is on-topic, to request a recommendation for 3rd party software is off-topic. It's one of the basic tenets of Stack Exchange - [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) Reddit thrives on opinions as to which is 'best', Stack Exchange doesn't.

Comment: Disagree - this is not a shopping Q - doesn't meet the criteria in your link - and I am done with this back-n-forth. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I don't make the rules, nor do I enforce them. The community, by democratic vote, will decide if this is on or off-topic. I'm done now, I'm not here to argue definitions.